# Atlassian SDK + Win10 => -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set

Tags: maven, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to use Atlassian SDK 6.2.9. on my laptop with Win10, but there is a maven problem.
Java:1.8.0_101
Mvn: 3.3.9 (M2_HOME)

CMD full stack says more:

```
c:\>atlas-version
ATLAS Version:    6.2.9
ATLAS Home:       C:\ProgramData\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.9
ATLAS Scripts:    C:\ProgramData\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.9\bin
ATLAS Maven Home: C:\ProgramData\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.9\apache-maven-3.2.1
AMPS Version:     6.2.6
--------
Executing: "C:\ProgramData\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.9\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\mvn.bat" --version -gs C:\ProgramData\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.9\apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/settings.xml
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.c:\>
```

My question is how can I figure this mvn problem out?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Seeing this (_C:\ProgramData\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.9\apache-maven-3.2.1_), you might have an issue having some environment variables (`M2_HOME` or `PATH`) pointing to a Maven 3.3.x version, whereas Atlassian SDK uses 3.2.x

Comment: Tome, thank you, you are right.